# Child Class in Superclass Array in Java

Tags: java, casting, arraylist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is `List&lt;Dog&gt;` a subclass of `List&lt;Animal&gt;`? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicit)

I have this code:

```
ArrayList<A> objects = new ArrayList<A>();

objects.add(new B());
```

where `B` is a child class o `A`. It gives me a compile time error like so:

The method add(A) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (B)

Comment: @SLaks: It's really not relevant in this case. Why do you need the classes?

Comment: Ignore that (my) close-vote. I had the question mixed up.

Comment: I'm going to check more carefully. I can't find the problem yet but this worked well before

Comment: @WChargin Why is it not relevant? The OP has some problems with the A <-> B relationship. We need to sort it out and if he gives us more info that will be helpful.

Comment: It's irrelevant because all you need is to know which class extends which. The implementation or rest of the structure is not important for polymorphism

Comment: Found the error. I was importing a class with the same name but in a different place

Comment: So if you would have shown us the code we could have seen that. Now everybody was guessing that you had mixed up the `A` and `B` relationship which you obviously had not.

Comment: The problem was in the imports

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This compiles and runs fine:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class A {
}

class B extends A {
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<A> arraylist = new ArrayList<A>();
        arraylist.add(new B());
    }
}
```

Have another look at your code. Perhaps you got it backwards and `A` extends `B`?

Comment: You mean `A` extends `B`

Comment: @Cratylus No, "`B` is a child class of `A`"

Comment: @Jeffrey -- that is the way it is *supposed* to be. he meant maybe the original code relationship was wrong.

Comment: @david Ahh, I skimmed over that part. Oops